# Python os.walk() failing

Tags: python, jython

I have created a script to give me the list of files in a folder directory. Yet, I am occasionally getting this error.  What does this mean?

portion of the error:

```
Script failed due to an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script>", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Nuix\Nuix 6\lib\jython.jar\Lib\os.py", line 309, in walk
  File "C:\Program Files\Nuix\Nuix 6\lib\jython.jar\Lib\os.py", line 299, in walk
  File "C:\Program Files\Nuix\Nuix 6\lib\jython.jar\Lib\genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
  File "C:\Program Files\Nuix\Nuix 6\lib\jython.jar\Lib\genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.python.modules.posix.PythonPOSIXHandler.error(Ljnr/constants/platform/Errno;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    at jnr.posix.BaseNativePOSIX.stat(BaseNativePOSIX.java:309)

    at jnr.posix.CheckedPOSIX.stat(CheckedPOSIX.java:265)

    at jnr.posix.LazyPOSIX.stat(LazyPOSIX.java:267)
```

The script:

```
import os
import codecs
import shutil
import datetime
import sys


exportpath = 'P:/Output/Export7/{6136BAF2-85BA-4E64-8C11-A2C59398FC02}/'
tempnativefolder = 'NATIVESOrig'


for dir, sub, file in os.walk(exportpath + tempnativefolder):
  for fname in file:
    #source path
    source = os.path.join(dir, fname).replace('\\', '/')
    print source


print("Natives moved to subfolders")
```

Comment: Have you checked for quirky permissions, weird filenames, and the like?

Comment: "java.lang ..."? Jython? That seems to originate from a JVM.

Comment: Maybe this?? http://bugs.jython.org/issue2131

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I found out that the presence of these characters(see "diamond with question mark" character in screenshot) in the file name causes the issue.  Once I replaced those, my script works.  thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

What the error means: `AbstractMethodError` means that some code tried to call a method which was not implemented.

`PythonPOSIXHandler` implements `jnr.posix.POSIXHandler`. JRuby also uses JNR and the interface is subtly different between the two. JRuby's newer copy of JNR has that one additional `#error(Errno, String, String)` method and Jython's implementation lacks that method, because it's compiled against the interface when the method didn't exist.

I usually see this problem in the other direction - where stuff in Jython's jar breaks JRuby. I assume it entirely depends on the order of the jars in the classpath.